# Checking if a tensors values are contained in another tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a torch tensor like so:

```py
a=[1, 234, 54, 6543, 55, 776]
```

and other tensors like so:

```py
b=[234, 54]
c=[55, 776]
```

I want to create a new mask tensor where the values of `a` will be true if there is another tensor (`b` or `c`) are equal to it.
For example, in the tensors we have above I would like to create the following masking tensor:

```py
a_masked =[False, True, True, False, True, True]
# The first two True values correspond to tensor `b` while the last two True values 
correspond to tensor `c`.
```

I have seen other methods to check whether a full tensor is contained in another but this isn't the case here.

Is there a torch way to do this efficiently?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answers to on the PyTorch forum [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/check-if-tensor-elements-in-a-value-list/67923), you could explicitly use a for loop, e.g.,

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([1, 234, 54, 6543, 55, 776])
b = torch.tensor([234, 54])
c = torch.tensor([55, 776])

a_masked = sum(a == i for i in b).bool() + sum(a == i for i in c).bool()

print(a_masked)
tensor([False,  True,  True, False, True, True])
```

However, there is actually a PyTorch [`isin`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isin.html#torch.isin) function, for which you could do:

```
a_masked = torch.isin(a, torch.cat([b, c]))
```

This is several times faster than the `sum` method.

Comment: @OfekGlick I just edited it to answer the full question as I forgot about `c`!

Comment: @OfekGlick I've just added a better and more efficient method to the answer.

Comment: your second alternative assumes that tensors `b` and `c` are always the same size right?

Comment: They have to be the same shape (i.e., same number of dimensions), but they can be different lengths and it will still work.